# How to get the html of a dynamic page using Scrapy and Splash?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I want to scrape the following website:

https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/

However, the source is just an script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"><title>IBM Science Summarizer</title><style>#teconsent {
        bottom: 120px !important;
      }</style><link href="/css/article.91dc9a3f.css" rel="prefetch"><link href="/css/faq.415c1d74.css" rel="prefetch"><link href="/css/search.4bc6e428.css" rel="prefetch"><link href="/js/article.8fdbbb61.js" rel="prefetch"><link href="/js/faq.6fba764e.js" rel="prefetch"><link href="/js/search.cdc7df37.js" rel="prefetch"><link href="/css/app.de6343fa.css" rel="preload" as="style"><link href="/css/chunk-vendors.9096ae02.css" rel="preload" as="style"><link href="/js/app.d95ff0b2.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.29fc9656.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/css/chunk-vendors.9096ae02.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/css/app.de6343fa.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but Scholar doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><div id="app"></div><script>// window.webpackHotUpdate is present in local development mode
      if (!window.webpackHotUpdate) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
        var script = document.createElement('script')

        script.type = 'text/javascript'
        script.src = 'https://www.ibm.com/common/stats/ida_stats.js'

        head.appendChild(script)
      }</script><script src="/js/chunk-vendors.29fc9656.js"></script><script src="/js/app.d95ff0b2.js"></script></body></html>
```

First I wanted to search via the form in the website, however `Scrapy` can't find the form. So I used `scrapy-spash` but it still can't find any form:

```
class IBMSSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """ A spider to collect articles from IBM SS website """
    name = 'ibmss'
    start_urls = [
        'https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/' # search?query=reading%20comprehension',
#   'http://google.com'
    ]
  
    def start_requests(self):
        print("start_urls:", self.start_urls)
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                args={
                # optional; parameters passed to Splash HTTP API
                'wait': 0.5,

                'url': url,
                # 'http_method' is set to 'POST' for POST requests
                # 'body' is set to request body for POST requests
                },
                #endpoint='render.json', # optional; default is render.html
                #splash_url='<url>',     # optional; overrides SPLASH_URL
                #slot_policy=scrapy_splash.SlotPolicy.PER_DOMAIN,  # optional
                ) 
 
    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'__BVID__377': 'reading comprehension' },
        formxpath='//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form',
            callback=self.parse_results
        )
    def parse_results(self, response):
        RESULT_LIST = '//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div'
        # RESULT_LIST = '//*div[contains(@class, "search-results")]//div[contains(@class, "result")]'
        result_listing = response.xpath(RESULT_LIST)

        pub_item = PaperItem(pub_type='archive')

        for result in result_listing:
            pub_url = response.urljoin(result.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "result-title")]/a/@href').extract_first())
  
            print(pub_url)            
            yield scrapy.Request(pub_url, callback=self.parse_paper_details,
                                 meta={'result':  pub_item})
```

Considering the source of the website, please guide me how can I run a scraper for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a disclaimer that I wasn't able to do this with Scrapy.

### Scraping Dynamic Content in Scrapy

I'm not sure what information you're requiring about the articles but here's a couple of things to think about when scraping dynamic content driven websites.

1. How much is the website driven by javascript ?
2. Is there an API I can re-engineering HTTP requests instead of automating browser activity?
   2.1) If so, do I need headers, parameters and cookies to mimic that request ?
3. Pre-rendering the page with splash
4. Last resort using selenium with scrapy
5. Using the selenium module directly in your scripts.

The reason's for going in this order is that with each one as a potential solution you're increasing the probability that your scraper is brittle and that efficiency of the scraper gets slower and slower.

Most efficient solution is to seek out an API.

### This Website

Checking the website you can see it's entirely driven by javascript which increases the chances of it making AJAX requests to an API end-point. Using chrome dev tools you can see there are 5 requests made to an API `https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search`

I often use the requests package to fiddle around with the API end point first. So in doing so I figured out that it really only needs the headers and your query. I assume you were looking at reading comprehension as a search so i've used that as an Example.

I will do a CURL copy of the request found in network tools and copy that into `curl.trillworks.com`, which converts the headers and etc into nice format.

For some reason, it's absolutely necessary to pass null in the data string to this API. However there is no null equivilent in passing a dictionary in python which is the way to be able to pass parameters in Scrapy (using the meta or cb_kwargs). I'd be interested to see others work on this to get it working in Scrapy. I may be missing something about passing the parameters in the request.

### Code Example

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

data = '{"query":"reading comprehension","filters":{},"page":0,"size":10,"sort":null,"sessionInfo":""}'

response = requests.post('https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search', headers=headers, data=data)

articles = response.json()['searchResults']['results']
for a in articles: 
    for b in a['sections']:
            title =  b['title']
            print(title)
            print('----------')
            for c in b['fragments']:
                text= c['text']
                print(text)
```

Here we are for looping around every search result article on that page, each section has a title which we're looping round and printing that, and then within that section there's fragments which has all the text on that page. We are then printing that.
Again I have no idea what you're doing with the information so I can't really specify any further, but you should be able to from that either store the text you require.

I must urge you to look at the json object yourself if there's additional data needs, it's all there you just have to do some json hunting. If you want the link to the ARVIX pdf then it's there too.

### Update to Comments

Here's the code example you would need to implement to make this work with scrapy.

```
import scrapy
import json

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/']
  
    headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    }
    cookies = {
    'dimsum_user': 'dce0087b-b1ed-4ceb-861a-6dcdc1af500f',
    'JSESSIONID': 'node01i38ra486o3eocapxvtryared1263001.node0',
    }
    data = {"query":"reading comprehension","filters":{},"page":0,"size":10,"sort":null,"sessionInfo":""}


    
    def start_requests(self):
        api_url = 'https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=api_url,method='POST',headers=self.headers,cb_kwargs={'data':self.data},cookies=self.cookies, callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse(self, response):
        articles = response.json()['searchResults']['results']
        for a in articles: 
           for b in a['sections']:
               title =  b['title']
               print(title)
               print('----------')
               for c in b['fragments']:
                   text= c['text']
                   print(text)
```

### Problem

Null is not a keyword in python and therefore can't be used as a dictionary and unfortunately it is necessary for `"sort":null` to used as the parameters that i've put in the data `variable`. I've tried converting this to JSON string without succcess too.

The error you get is

```
data = {"query":"reading comprehension","filters{},"page":0,"size":10,"sort":null,"sessionInfo":""}

NameError: name 'null' is not defined`NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

#### Essential scrapy log

```
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <POST https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <POST https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search> (referer: https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/)
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <500 https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-07-30 13:10:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Open to ideas and suggestions for this problem.

Comment: Thank you, I want to extract the text content of each article. Yes, I also can skip the search form and make a query (with the url) or javascript. However, in your example, I can't see the text for the article. If you search "reading comprehension", some articles are listed, then I want to click on each link (the title) and the whole text for the article opens. then I want to extract the content of that article...

Comment: Do you mean the text of the pdf or text of the links from the search results ? It's always best to be as specific as possible about what you're doing in your original question.

Comment: Code has been updated to print each links abstract... etc..., this only works for the first 9 results on that page though. There are additional HTTP requests you'll need to make for to get the next page results. But this code gives you the structure to do that. It's just a case of seeing how to make requests on the next page etc...

Comment: Thank you very much! I meant the text in the website (not pdf), yeah it works nicely! You think if it can be merged with scrapy-splah? However, it's good as it is.

Comment: I'll put up the code you could implement for this request in scrapy. I don't necessarily think there's a need to use splash if all your data needs are met. As I said introducing splash reduces the data efficiency. Essentially if anyone can find a way to allow python to accept a null value in a dictionary you could post the parameters needed to use the api request in scrapy. I have done a search and haven't found this. I'll keep looking tonight and report back if I find a way through.

Comment: You could also argue that unless you're making huge requests on the servers the efficiency of using scrapy may not be required.

Comment: Also if you do think the code i've provided is acceptable to answer your query, I would appreciate a tick. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Thank you very much! wish I could give it more up votes :)

Comment: sorry, could you please guide me how to apply some filters? I didn't get where from you caught that json. Anyway, I posted this question for my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204368/web-requests-json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-ch