# Web requests: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I try to get some data using json requests to a [website](https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/):

```
import requests

headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Origin': 'https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Referer': 'https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    }
    data = f'{{"query":"{query}","filters":{{"year":2020}},"page":{page},"size":10,"sort":null,"sessionInfo":""}}'
    #data = '{"query":"reading comprehension","filters":{},"page":0,"size":10,"sort":null,"sessionInfo":""}'
    print("data:", data)
    response = requests.post('https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search', headers=headers, data=data)
```

I get the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The program works if I use `"filters":{{}}`. I'm not sure how can I pass filters to it or whether it has a field named "year" or not. I don't know if the error is due to syntax or absence of the field.

Comment: try this, ```data = f'{{"query":"{query}","filters":{{"year":"{year}"}},"page":{page},"size":10,"sort":null,"sessionInfo":""}}'```

Comment: @Sushanth thanks, it works now, why, I don't know!

Comment: For your ref this is the api, https://dimsum.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud/api/scholar/search you will need search on browser network console.

Comment: @Sushanth thanks, however I didn't get how to search on browser network console and how I can find out the api.